# $_GET and $_POST issue

Tags: php

The following is my problem (example code)..

If I perform this:

```
$rf = $_GET['_id'];

if($_POST['form']){
echo "ref: " . $rf;
}
```

`$rf` is blank during `if($_POST['form'])`

Now, If I perform this:

```
$rf = "123456";

if($_POST['form']){
echo "ref: " . $rf;
}
```

`$rf` is displayed

Why is it blank the first time and not blank if I assign something static to the $rf var?
Also how can I fix this so the first solution works?

Thanks!

Note: don't worry about SQL injections.. I have already stripped everything from "_id".

**Complete PHP and HTML**

```
<?php

require "includes/connect.php";
//var_dump($_GET);die;

function gen_code($codeLen = 7) {     
$code = '';     
for ($i=0; $i<$codeLen; $i++) {         
 $d=rand(1,30)%2;       
 $code .= $d ? chr(rand(65,90)) : chr(rand(48,57));      }  
 return $code; 
 }  


 function add_code($email_id) {
 global $mysqli;
 $code = gen_code(7); 
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET code='" . $code ."' WHERE email_id='" . $email_id . "'");  
 if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1) {   
 add_code($email_id);  
 } else return $code; } 

$msg = '';
$referrer = $_GET['_url'];
// echo $referrer displays the referrer ID contents correctly

if ( ! empty($referrer))
{
$mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE code='" . $referrer ."'");
}

if (!empty($_POST['email'])){


    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
        } else {   
          $email_code = add_code($mysqli->insert_id); 
        } 

        $msg = "http://www.my-url/" . $email_code;

        //the following doesn't work as referrer is now empty :(
        if ( ! empty($referrer))
        {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET signup = signup + 1 WHERE code='" . $referrer ."'");
        }

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('msg' => $msg)));
        }

    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="launch">


    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $msg;?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>

    <div id="invite">
    <p style="margin-top:20px;">The ID of who referred you: <?php echo $referrer; //this displays correctly?>)</p>
    <p style="margin-top:20px;"><span id="code" style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>


</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Binding event listeners for the form on document ready

    $('#email').defaultText('Your Email Address');

    // 'working' prevents multiple submissions
    var working = false;

    $('#form').submit(function(){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.post("./index.php",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r){

            if(r.error){
                $('#email').val(r.error);
                        } else {
                $('#email').val(r.msg);
            }


            working = false;
        },'json');

        return false;
    });
});

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

    var element = this.eq(0);
    element.data('defaultText',value);

    element.focus(function(){
        if(element.val() == value){
            element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
            element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
        }
    });

    return element.blur();
}
```

Comment: Are you having _id be set to anything during $_POST['form']?  This seems that you are just not setting the $_GET variable in the URL.

Comment: What happens if you echo `$_GET['_id']` as the first line in that code? Is anything shown?

Comment: How about removing the references to $_POST['form'] as they are clearly not relevant?

Comment: @Flipper: $_GET is grabbed via htaccess through the URL. If I `echo $rf;` prior to the `if($_POST['form']){` it displays fine, just not within the `if($_POST['form']){`

Comment: @Sam Starling: Yup - it's shown. Just not during $_POST

Comment: I assume your form signature is something like `<form action="submit.php?_id=123456" method="POST">`?

Comment: @DontCare4Free: I need it there as I only want the DB updated with $rf once the user submits the form..

Comment: @DT85: And it does print "ref: " in the first example?

Comment: @Brad Christie: Form is `<form id="form" method="post" action="">` and htaccess line is `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: @DontCare4Free: Yup - it only prints "ref: ", meaning $rf is blank.

Comment: @DT85: Have you confirmed the RewriteRule is being called and is working?

Comment: @Brad Christie: using `var_dump($_GET);die;` displays: `array(1) { ["_id"]=> string(7) "1234567" }`

Comment: @DT85: Then it comes down to how you're comparing your values. You probably need to look at `isset()`/`empty()` instead of `if(var)`

Comment: @Brad Christie: I just tried, `if ( ! empty($_POST['form'])){` and still no luck..

Comment: @DT85: What does `var_dump($_POST);exit;` return?

Comment: @Brad Christie: placed at the top of page.. `array(0) { } ` this is because I have not submitted the form yet correct?

Comment: @Brad Christie: placed just after `if($_POST['form']){` and the form won't submit..

Comment: @DT85: You tell me? Perform the var dump on the same page/instance where you're trying to check if `$_POST['form']` exists.

Comment: @Brad Christie: using ajax so everything is handled on the one page. if i perform the var dump once i submit, it halts the script and nothing is dumped.

Comment: @DT85: Well, to avoiding having to debug more than one thing at a time, the code you're working on should be separated. Make a generic HTML page with a single form on it simulating what the AJAX does. Once you've confirmed it to behave as expected, then bring AJAX back in to the picture.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Just performed `if (!empty($_POST['form'])){
$post = $_POST['form'];
echo $post;
}` and it echo's out the email.

Comment: @DT85: Then I'd say it's probably the AJAX if it works without AJAX. If you have FireFox, open the Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K) and see if the data is being sent in the format you expect.

Comment: Brad Christie: I do indeed :) 5 mins.. just grabbing the RC4 of FF as earlier versions doen't have web console, just the deprecated error console.

Comment: @Brad Christie: [06:22:40.576] GET http://www.my-url.com/1234567 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 352ms]  [06:22:49.595] POST http://www.my-url.com/index.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1330ms] - form=test%40test.com

Comment: @DT85: As an alternative, you could grab the TamperData plugin for FF3.X

Comment: @Brad Christie: TamperData displays everything correctly, with 200 success codes and just as above, with the correct data. Would it help if i uploaded the php, js and html on pastebin and shared the url?

Comment: @DT85: More code is better than less. ;-) Or just update your post with those pieces pasted in, using the "code" formatting.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Pasted all my code. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Any idea? It's really annoying.. can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: @DT85: Does `$ajax` populate correctly, even after the Rewrite by any chance?

Comment: @Brad Christie: Sorry, which bit.. in JS? Everything runs smoothly even after the Rewrite. It is just the use of $_GET within $_POST which I'm trying to workaround. I know you can't use get within post but I don't know how to sort the code so I can have it working the way I require :/

Comment: @DT85: You can use GET & POST, that's why I feel it's something else inhibiting what you're going for. I would remove the JSON encode and have the AJAX dump pure text. Then, add a bunch of `echo 'a';` `echo 'b'` etc. in your PHP script and see which (expected) step of the script is failing based on if `abcd` was shown, but maybe `efg` (like you were expecting) didn't. Get what I'm saying?

Comment: @Brad Christie: YOU GENIUS Brad! Ok so what I did was `};//,'json');` in JS and commented out `$ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');` in index.php. That did the trick. Now with that removed, I don't have AJAX working with the hide and show of div's :/ How can that be sorted?

Comment: @DT85: Now bring the `,'json');` back and see if it works (less the `if($ajax)` check in your script. And, instead of checking a referring header i would add a different flag to check for on the PHP side.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Now the form won't submit once I bring back the `,'json');`

Comment: @Brad Christie: Can't seem to get the div's showing AND have the DB updating with the $_GET value. It's one or the other at the moment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_GET['_id'] is apparently empty in your code.

you are loading no `example.com/5ABH67L` url.
you are loading `/index.php` as it's clearly seen from `script.js`.

you have to either

- add current url to POST data using javascript.
- or make POST action not index.php but current location.

I am not a JS pro, but try this:

```
$.post("",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r)
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: AHA! so in script.js I would put `/index.php...` how can I grab the _url again using JS, from htaccess? Or what must be placed in that url to reference the referrer? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DT85 i think you have to post onto current location. try to use empty action or `document.location`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I tried empty as per your example and also `document.location` - still nothing :(

Comment: @DT85 first, get your browser some addon to show HTTP headers, like LiveHTTPHeaders for Firefox, and see, what url being requested with this AJAX call. if its not current URL, ask under JS tag, how to send AJAX call to the current location

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I just upgraded to FF r4 and the addon is not compatible. I'll try use tamperdata..

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: WOOOO!! Ok so I did this `$.post("./index.php?_url=AAAAAAA",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r){` and the header was correct and it outputted the variable, etc etc. Now the question is, how do I replace the "AAAAAAA" with the current url? ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: You were RIGHT. `$.post("",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r)`.. all I had to do within the `if($_POST..` was: `$referrer = $_GET['_url'];` again. Thank you so SO MUCH!! Absolutely champion. I'm amazed no-one else picked up on this!!

Comment: @DT85 I just spent so much blood and sweat on .htaccess redirects already :) Glad you got it at last

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I could only imagine. What a pain in the a**! Thank you again - so glad you're around on S.O. to help others.

Answer (score 1):

As you're probobly sending form by POST request you should try to get _id by $_POST['_id'], however [$_REQUEST[] array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) may by of more use to you.

```
if($_POST['form']){
    echo "ref: " . $_POST['_id'];
}
```

Comment: Exactly, use $_REQUEST[] instead of $_GET or $_POST!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that $_GET is not been set, you mention that it is set by the .htaccess file from the URL are you sure that this is working?

try:

```
var_dump($_GET);die;
```

and see what happens.

Comment: using `var_dump($_GET);die;` displays: `array(1) { ["_id"]=> string(7) "1234567" }`

Comment: Updated code in my original question. You were right, outside of the _POST, _GET is not empty, however within _POST it's empty. How can I fix this so _GET (or the variable assigned to it, $referrer) is NOT empty? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just because `$_POST['form']`  evaluates to `true` that doesn't mean that `$_GET['_id']` is set as well.

In general you should always check, if those variables are set, before you access their content. You can do that by checking `isset($_GET['_id'])`. So you could replace your `if` like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['form']) && isset($_GET['_id']) )
{
    $rf = $_GET['_id'];
    echo "ref: " . $rf;
}
```

Comment: @poke: shouldn't I be using `if ( ! empty($_POST['form'])`..? Also seeing as though, it shouldn't be empty, how can I resolve the issue I'm having?

Comment: That's not the same. `empty` just checks for the content, but it does not make sure, that the index does exist (and as such, a value was set). You should *always* check those values first with `isset` (you will get a warning when you use an index for which no value was set).. The reason, why those values are not set, is probably due to your HTML form (you are probably not sending the GET variable with your POST).

Comment: @poke: thanks for taking the time to provide the explanation. how can i send a GET using a POST?

Comment: That's not totally true, poke, empty($array['missing_array_var']) will _not_ throw a warning, in the same manner as isset. So, you don't have to check isset before checking with empty.

Comment: As well, empty() returns true for zero values. `$x = 0; empty($x); // TRUE`. It's a bad way to check if there's something in a variable, because it flat out lies to you.

Comment: Yeah, regardless of what content you would expect, you should still use `isset` first, just to be safe.

Comment: @Marc B, @poke: I've updated my question with complete code. Do you know what the issue could be?