# Unassigning a variables value from $_GET

Tags: php

I use;

```
$referrer = $_GET['_url'];
```

If I `echo $referrer;` it will display correctly.

If I use $referrer within a $_POST, it is empty. I think due to $referrer being assigned to $_GET.
How can I extract the *value of $referrer* into another variable so it is no longer assigned to the $_GET?

I hope that makes sense..

Comment: what do you mean with "I use $referrer within a $_POST"?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I'll give you my example in your answer..

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` will only contain data IF you send that from form.

So, your code is basically right. Because you use referrer from within your URL.

If you really want to have `$referer` from `$_POST`, you will have to code something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="somewhere.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="_url" value="{place the referrer here}" />
</form>
```

Or, like @Michael Gillette answer, you can change that with [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: will that work in my application? this thing is really bugging me! My complete code: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5363810/get-and-post-issue

Answer (score 1):

> hope that makes sense..

sorry, but it doesn't :)

1. `$referrer` become distinct variable with no relation to `$_GET['_url']`. It already contains value extracted from $_GET
2. there are not a single reason for $_GET sourced variables to conflict with $_POST.

Your problem is somewhere else. 
It seems you're just trying to access variable that doesn't exist. Because every variable dies along with whole PHP after it's execution.

PHP scripts execution is atomic. It's not like a desktop application constantly running in your browser, and not even a demon with persistent connection to your desktop application. It's more like a command line utility - doing it's job and exits. It runs discrete:

1. a browser makes a call
2. PHP wakes up, creates an HTML page, sends it to the browser **and dies**
3. Browser renders that HTML and shows it to the user.
4. User clicks a link
5. a browser makes a call
6. **another PHP instance, knowing nothing of the previous call,  wakes up** and so on

So, if you set your $referrer in one instance and trying to access it in another, it will fail. You have to re-sent it's value with next call

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I've been trying to figure out this issue for 2 days now.. I'm trying to understand why $referrer becomes empty and how to resolve it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363810/get-and-post-issue

Comment: @DT85 $_GET['_url'] is apparently empty in your other question. Why do you expect it and what for?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Scenario: `$referrer = "1234567"`. Ok so when the user submits their email address in the form, `if ($_POST['email']){`, it should do: `$mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET signup = signup + 1 WHERE code='" . $referrer ."'");` and in JS it should hide the form and show the other div. `$referrer` is not empty before and after the `if ($_POST['email']){`, only during. I need it because if the user signs up, it should update the referrer's "signup" column (by using a lookup of $referrer in the DB) in the DB with a count+1 to say "they have referred another person".

Comment: @DT85 you are taking it ALL wrong. referrer IS empty. _url is not set by htaccess rules. why do you think it should be set and what value do you expect?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Also if I set `$referrer = "1234567"` instead of `$referrer = $_GET['_url'];`, it updates the DB during the `if ($_POST` bit :) Only when using $_GET it doesn't update the DB..

Comment: @DT85 you should show more complete code. This could be anything

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: If I load the url: example.com/5ABH67L htaccess should assign `5ABH67L` to `"_url"` and the page redirects to example.com. I then use `$_GET['_url']` to load the value of what was in the url which I call `$referrer` which should be `5ABH67L`. If I have gone about this the wrong way, I'm happy to adjust according to your recommendations :)

Comment: @Pekka: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5363810/get-and-post-issue - I just didn't want to duplicate questions.. rather trying to figure out the answer with another question :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Why _url should be set? I thought this would set it: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clone` keyword, as seen in the examples in this article:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: __clone method called on non-object

Answer (score 0):

could you post an example of what you might like to do?

```
$referrer = $_REQUEST['_url'];
```

will return true on both GET and POST requests

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gillette - My complete example: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5363810/get-and-post-issue